# FTP fopen() error 550—not a plain file

Tags: php, ftp

Well, this is a problem I have never seen before.

I am trying to stream an FTP file using PHP's `fopen()` and `feof()` in order to copy it from one server to my own. This works fine when using normal `http://` URLs. However, when using the `ftp://` protocol, I'm receiving the following error:

```
fopen(ftp://.../streaming/planted2.mp4) [0function.fopen0]: failed to open stream: FTP server reports 550 /streaming/planted2.mp4: not a plain file.
```

---

Bear in mind that I have confirmed the URL is correct.

If I pop it into my browser's search bar, it always loads correctly.

Following this error, any attempt to use `feof()` or `fread()` on the wrapper results in an error complaining that the respective function expects a resource, but that instead a boolean is being provided. This would not be the case if `fopen()` was not failing.

As the files are quite large (several gigabytes at times) streaming is mandatory. Also, due to the configuration of the server, I need a way to loop through each chunk in order to buffer some output. If I don't, the server holds up. It's a weird configuration on Rackspace's behalf. That's why I'm using `feof()`.

So, without further ado, **my question is this:** What does the 550 error mean, and what is a "plain file"? If it is a problem with the configuration of the server I am attempting to download from, what are my options, given my limitations?

### EDIT

I have determined this is a server issue. However, the problem is still unresolved.

I contacted my boss and our server administrator, and the server guy told me to test this out on a different Windows-based server instead of the Linux-based one I was playing with. My script works with the Windows server, so I have confirmed my script is not in error.

Unfortunately, my boss still wants me to figure out the problem, and find out why it's not working on the Linux box. I have absolutely no idea why, and don't know where to look. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I contacted my boss and our server administrator, and the server guy told me to test this out on a different Windows-based server instead of the Linux-based one I was playing with. My script works with the Windows server, so I have confirmed my script is not in error.

Comment: My boss still wants me to figure out the problem, and find out why it's not working on the Linux box. I have absolutely no idea why, and don't know where to look. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across this issue when trying to get a file from a sco unix server.

Server File Location: /home/user/data/myfile.csv

I can put the below into any browser and it gets the file.

```
ftp://user:password@host/data/myfile.csv
```

However if I run the below, I get the same error as you

```
$f = fopen("ftp://user:password@host/data/myfile.csv", "r");
```

However, if I put the full path into fopen - it works fine.

```
$f = fopen("ftp://user:password@host/home/user/data/myfile.csv", "r");
```

I'm not sure if this will fix it for you, but works for me.